# Unable to switch to a dialog box in Selenium-WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I clicked on a button a new dialog box appeared in the same browser. Is it possible to switch to the dialog box in Selenium-WebDriver using Java?

I found that it's not an alert or there is no iframe present in the page.
As soon as the dialog box opens the parent window page is loading until I close the box and the new window appears in the same browser.
I tried window handles option but none of them solved my issue.
Please suggest a solution to this?

Comment: Consider it as a _Modal Dialog Box_ from the same _HTML DOM_

Answer (score 0):

if the window object is identifiable using AutoIT spy tool, then you can simply use AutoIT java wrapper classes. The code will look something like this,

```
WindowObject = ApplicationObject.FindWindow("Your window title goes here");
WindowObject.ControlClick("Windowtitle","",ControlID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Modal Dialog Box, you can do something like: 

`driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept(); // TO ACCEPT THE ALERT
OR
alert().dismiss(); // TO DISMISS IT WITHOUT ACCEPTING`